# Unique class or id for each element in D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

Is there a way to uniquely set the classes or id's of the elements in D3js?

for example, I am now using a bar chart and these are how the bar rectangle elements look like.

```
<g class="g" transform="translate(17,0)"></g>
<g class="g" transform="translate(34,0)"></g>
<g class="g" transform="translate(51,0)"></g>
...
<g class="g" transform="translate(850,0)"></g>
<g class="g" transform="translate(867,0)"></g>
```

i want them to look like this:

```
<g1 class="g" transform="translate(17,0)"></g>
<g2 class="g" transform="translate(34,0)"></g>
<g3 class="g" transform="translate(51,0)"></g>
...
<g50 class="g" transform="translate(850,0)"></g>
<g51 class="g" transform="translate(867,0)"></g>
```

or something like:

```
<g class="g1" transform="translate(17,0)"></g>
<g class="g2" transform="translate(34,0)"></g>
<g class="g3" transform="translate(51,0)"></g>
...
<g class="g50" transform="translate(850,0)"></g>
<g class="g51" transform="translate(867,0)"></g>
```

i'm currently finding resources on how to dynamically change the iteration. the reason why i'm doing this is because i need to control each element for functions such as changing color or changing the width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example you've given won't work -- you can't change the name of the elements themselves in SVG, as it won't know how to interpret them. To set classes, you can do something like

```
d3.selectAll("g")
  .attr("class", function(d, i) { return "g" + (i+1); });
```

or the same when creating the elements. Alternatively, you can set IDs (which seems to be better for what you're doing) as pointed out in the other answer:

```
d3.selectAll("g")
  .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "g" + (i+1); });
```

Note that if you have bound data to those elements, you can also use D3's [`.filter()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter) to select the elements you want. Using IDs or classes is going to be easier in almost all cases though.

Answer (score 0):

When you're setting the other properties, add this:

```
.attr("id", function(d,i) {return "Name" + i;})
```